# Cannot resolve symbol 'LocationRequest' Android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-gps, google-location-services

I'm new on Android programming, I try to use the new Location Service for getting the user position, to do this i follow the official android developer guide but I don't understand why I'm not able to import LocationRequest in my fragment class.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
```

here is my Gradle app file:

> build.gradle

```
 ..
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
 }
```

and this is what I include in my Manifest file

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
...
```

what i do wrong?

Comment: You should add also,  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'

Answer (score 18):

add dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'

Comment: for more detail refer to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 3):

Add this line when importing in the main activity

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Import these dependencies in your build.gradle file....

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.niqo01.rxplayservices:rx-play-services-location:0.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can import `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;`
in to your activity you need to add `com.github.niqo01.rxplayservices:rx-play-services-location:0.4.0` as a library dependency in the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding "implementation 'com.github.niqo01.rxplayservices:rx-play-services-location:0.4.0'" in the graddle